# naming output files using variable parameters and input filenames in bash

Tags: bash, parameters, output, filenames

I have a series of files in sub-directories that I want to loop through, process, and name according to the input filename and the various parameters (models) I'm using to process the files.

For example file names like AG005574, AG004788, AG003854 and parameter/model values like ATd, PZa, RTK1, so I want to end with files like 
AG005574_ATd 
AG005574_PZa 
AG005574_RTK1
AG004788_ATd
AG004788_PZa
etc.
I loop through the subfolders, run the process and output the results like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

model=$1
for file in $(find /path/to/files/*/ -type f -name 'AG*.fa');
     do output=${model}"_"${file} ;
        process_call --out=$output."tab" --options ../Path/to/model/$1.hmm $file ;
    echo $file
done
```

I want to be able to specify the model on the command-line (hence the model=$1). However, my approach does not work in general; I can get the output named by model using

```
do output=$model ;
```

but this also writes only the last file processed because it over-writes all the others (and no input filename is used). Any help/tutoring is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need semicolons at the ends of lines in general. Replace `output=${model}"_"${file}` with `output="${model}_${file}"`.  Those are general observations, not answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that when the file name given by `find` is:

```
/path/to/files/xyz/AG002378.fa
```

your `output` parameter becomes, for `$1` as `ATd`,

```
ATd_/path/to/files/xyz/AG002378.fa
```

instead of:

```
/path/to/files/xyz/AG002378_ATd
```

That is, you want the `.fa` removed, and the `_ATd` added.

The classic commands for this are `dirname` and `basename`:

```
dir=$(dirname "$file")
base=$(basename "$file" .fa)
output="$dir/${file}_$1"
```

There are tricks you can do with:

```
base_with_suffix=${file##*/}
base=${base_with_suffix%.fa}
```

which do not invoke an external command.  The `dirname` operation can be done too:

```
dir=${file%/*}
```

but I think `basename` and `dirname` are clearer (but I could be biassed by many years experience during which there wasn't an alternative).  Also, there are edge cases where the string manipulation expressions don't work well but the commands work correctly, but they are unlikely to actually impact your code.

It is not entirely clear from your question exactly what you want as the output, but variations on the themes shown should allow you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan! I will play around with these.

Answer (score 1):

Pass ALL the model names as parameters to the script:

```
/path/to/script ATd PZa RTK1
```

then

```
#!/bin/bash    
find /path/to/files/*/ -type f -name 'AG*.fa' | 
while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo "$file"
    for model in "$@"; do
        output="${file%.fa}_$model.tab"
        process_call --out="$output" --options "../Path/to/model/$model.hmm" "$file"
    done
done
```

If you already know all the models, you can build that into the script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
models=( ATd PZa RTK1 )
...
    for model in "${models[@]}"; do
...
```